# How to list GCP projects with a particular API enabled

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Is it possible to take a a list of all projects in a organization that uses a specific API, e.g Cumpute Engine API?

Answer (score 5):

[Cloud Asset Inventory](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory) should help.

It's a slightly confusing interface but try:

```sh
ORG=[[YOUR-ORG-ID]]

gcloud asset search-all-resources \
--scope=organizations/${ORG} \
--asset-types=serviceusage.googleapis.com/Service \
--query=name:compute.googleapis.com
```